# Función en javascript que modifica propiedades de un objeto

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

La funcion llamada 'agregaPropiedad' recibe como argumento un array llamado 'amigos' que contiene:

- en cada posición del arreglo un objeto que puede tener como propiedades 'nombre' o 'edad'.
- También recibe un string llamado 'propiedad'.
- Esta funcion debe agregar la propiedad 'propiedad' y setearla en null a aquellos objetos dentro de 'amigos' que no tengan esa propiedad
- Debe devolver el array 'amigos' modificado.
- Nota: Si el objeto dentro de 'amigos' tiene esa 'propiedad' no modificarla.

Ejemplo:

```
 var amigos = [{ nombre: 'toni' } , { nombre: 'Emi', edad: 25 }];
  agregaPropiedad(amigos, 'edad')
```

Debe devolver:

```
[{ nombre: 'toni', edad: null } , { nombre: 'Emi', edad: 25 }]
```

Función:

```
function agregaPropiedad(amigos, propiedad) {

    Object.defineProperty(amigos, 'propiedad',{
        value : "null",
    });

    return amigos;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

La funcion de añadir propiedad recorre tu array de objetos y aquellos que no tengan esa propiedad se le añade con valor nulo.

```js
function addProperty (array, property) {
    array.forEach(function (item) {
    if (!item.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        item[property] = null; 
    }
  })
  
  return array;
}

let amigos = [
    {
    name: 'Toni'
  }, 
  {
    name: 'Emi',
    edad: 25
  }
];

let amigosModificado = addProperty(amigos, 'edad');

console.log(amigosModificado);
```